# deployment on minikube locally

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes, minikube, socketcluster

I have deployed and created services for  `socketcluster`, `scc-broker` and `scc-state` on `kubernetes` locally via `minikube` directly through using the docker-files (see this [link](https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster/tree/master/kubernetes) for `.yaml` files). And I have also created a service for `ingress` within the same cluster with the `.yaml` file provided in the link that I have mentioned.  As far as I understand by default these services are of `ClusterIP` type.

Deployment of the services is working properly on the vm (minikube).
Status is set to running on the Kubernetes dashboard for

- pods
- deployment

But the issue I am facing is that there is no public endpoints exposed from scc-state, scc-broker, socketcluster server.
So currently I am not able to understand how do I access the services externally i.e. outside the virtual machine (that is running on minikube).

The images were built from the kubernetes yml files directly, with the ingress TLS security disabled.

Am I missing out on any aspect as to how to access the socketcluster on the host machine? Should I specify the service type to any other type other than `ClusterIP` as I know that using this type ensures that the service will be exposed within cluster only. But again my doubt is that if I am using `ingress` , it should help access the services outside the vm. Do I need to have an `ingress controller` separately such as NGINX ?

Any lead will be appreciate.

Thanks!

P.S. Following [this](https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster/blob/master/scc-guide.md) guide to for the deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes doesn't expose anything outside the private container network unless you specifically tell it to. The common ways to do that are

- Use a `Service` with `type: LoadBalancer` to get a public IP attached to a cloud service. This isn't available on minikube
- Use a `Service` with `type: NodePort` to expose a port on each node's public network. This is the recommended way to do things on minikube (https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#networking)
- Create your pods with `hostNetwork: true` to skip the container network and use the host network (e.g. sharing the same IP as the node itself). This is generally less useful than the previous two options except in very specific circumstances.

The `Ingress` resource isn't related to external connectivity. If you have an ingress-controller deployed, it will use the `Ingress` resources you create to configure itself. For example, the nginx-ingress-controller (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/nginx) will essentially create a `server` block in the nginx configuration for each `Ingress`. However, the ingress-controller itself would still need to be exposed to the external network using a `Service` with `type: LoadBalancer` or `type: NodePort`.

Comment: So do you mean that ..? I don't need to have any ingress/ingress controller service if I just put my services in the `kubernetes` as NodePort type ..??

Comment: That's correct. If you set your service as `type: NodePort`, the underlying pods will be exposed on the IP of minikube (e.g. 192.168.99.1)

Comment: Thanks @coreypobrien !

Comment: One more question, As I am going to have multiple replica of pods for scaling purpose, so in that case I need to have a load balancer deployed insider the kubernetes which does the reverse-proxy, am I right ..?

Comment: You still shouldn't need anything besides the service. A Kubernetes `Service` with `type: ClusterIP` will direct connections to any available pod. Here's a graphic from the docs: https://kubernetes.io/images/docs/services-iptables-overview.svg

Answer (score 1):

If you follow minikube documentation, https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#quickstart, it tells you to create a `Service` with `type: NodePort`.

Then run `kubectl get services` to find the assigned IP number for your service, and use `minikube ip` to find IP address of minikube VM. Then put these two together and access the service from your laptop.

Comment: thanks for your response, but what I think that putting services as clusterIP/NodePort will not effect if I am using an ingress controller to expose my services to outside world .correct me if I am wrong.